# find date format from string using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview

My clients machine datetime is different from one another. 
so i have to make sure that my code of comparing two different datetimes should work.

I have Datagridview and 2 datetime fields(Operation Start Date Time and Operation End Date Time).

condition : both fields should be lesser than or equal to current date time.

On cell validating i am checking Operation End DateTime < Current DateTime
in this time i am getting `String is not valid datetime`.
How can we solve this issue ? please suggest.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView.Columns("Timein").Index Then                
   If DateTime.Parse(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein").EditedFormattedValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now) Then
    MessageBox.Show("TimeIn should not be greater than today's date", "Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    DataGridView.EditingControl.Text = DateTime.Now
    Exit Sub
   End If
End If
```

Comment: If you know the exact format of the date from client you can use datetime.parseexasct method

Comment: Shouldn't `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(` be `DateTime.Parse(` You don't need to parse a parsed value.

Comment: What i would like to know is..why the hell are you converting dates to string in order to compare them? Just do this `If DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein") > DateTime.Now Then`

Comment: @Pikoh that's a very good point. Would `DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein")` not be an `Object` though? Would you not need to convert to `Date` to them compare to `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: @Bugs yes probably, but a simple `CType`should do i guess: `If CType(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein"),DateTime) > DateTime.Now Then`

Comment: The point is you should always compare dates as `DateTime`, parsing them to string is a source of multiple problems

Comment: @Pikoh Definitely the point here. No need to convert to string and no need to parse a parsed value.

Comment: CType(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein"),DateTime) > DateTime.Now<br> showing error conversion from String to Date is not a valid"

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value) > DateTime.Now`

Comment: @Pikoh you are missing the `.Value` as `DataGridViewCell` can't be cast to `DateTime`

Comment: I have added CType(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein").edittedformattedvalue,DateTime) > DateTime.Now then also getting same error conversion from string to date is not a valid

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value) > DateTime.Now </br> is working but if I change the system date format on click of cell showing "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: You are right @Slai. Should be `If CType(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein").Value,DateTime) > DateTime.Now Then`

Answer (score 0):

First convert it to date with CDate and remove the Parsing:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView.Columns("Timein").Index Then                
   If CDate(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("Timein").EditedFormattedValue) > DateTime.Now Then
    MessageBox.Show("TimeIn should not be greater than today's date", "Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    DataGridView.EditingControl.Text = DateTime.Now
    Exit Sub
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Adding CDate  code showing error "Value of type Date cannot be converted to Boolean"

Comment: Conversion from string "23/02/2017 01:43 PM" to type 'Date' is not valid.exception is throwing